# Jquery to collapse expanded div on click

Tags: jquery, html

My Html looks like

```
<h3><a href="#" title="story title">Story Title</a>
    <img class="expandstory" src="/images/plus.png" /></h3>
<div class="description">Short description about the story</div>

<h3><a href="#" title="story title">Story Title</a>
    <img class="expandstory" src="/images/plus.png" /></h3>
<div class="description">Short description about the story</div>
```

My jquery looks like

```
$(".expandstory").click(function()  {
   $(".description").slideUp(500);
   $(this).parent().nextAll('.description:first').slideToggle(500);
   $(this).attr('src','/images/minus.png');
});
```

Everything works fine. But when I click on minus image the div collapses and expands again. How to make the div collapse and not to expand. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are sliding it up first, and then sliding it down by toggle:

```
$(".description").slideUp(500); // Slide up
$(this).parent().nextAll('.description:first').slideToggle(500); // slide down
```

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve but it looks as if that first line should go.

Comment: He is trying to close all other descriptions before opening the one he clicked for

Answer (score 0):

Try changing/adding a class to the image and bind different functions:

```
$(".expandstory").not('.close').click(function()  {
   $(".description").slideUp(500);
   $(this).parent().nextAll('.description:first').slideToggle(500);
   $(this).attr('src','/images/minus.png').addClass('close');
});
$(".expandstory.close").click(function()  {
   $(".description").slideUp(500);
   $(this).attr('src','/images/plus.png').removeClass('close');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It collapses and expands because you're calling the `slideUp` method all your `.description` dividers (including the one you're wanting to close), and then calling `slideToggle`.

What you can do is change your first `.slideUp` to *not* target the `:first` divider:

```
$(".description")
    .not($(this).parent().nextAll('.description:first')).slideUp(500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CqC8r/

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code:

```
$(".expandstory").click(function()  {
   $(".description").slideUp(500);
   $(this).parent().nextAll('.description:first').slideToggle(500);
   $(this).attr('src','/images/minus.png');
});
```

Those first two lines interact with the corresponding `.description` element twice. Once when selecting all of them and sliding those up, and then again when getting only the next `.description` element - you then call `.slideToggle()` which will slide it down again (because it's already up).

I would suggest that your initial state is all descriptions closed so that you don't need the `$(".description").slideUp(500);` line, and then you can just toggle the `.description` element that corresponds to the `<h3>/<img>` clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

The following will do as you require:

```
 <script>
 $(function() {
     $(".expandstory").click(function()  {
         $(this).parent().next("div").slideToggle(500);
     });
 });
 </script>
```

It allows you to also expand the description after it was closed.

Try it out here:
[Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cSzRm/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".expandstory").click(function()  {
   $(this).parent().nextAll('.description:first').slideToggle(500);
});
```

and here is the working version of your code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SamirAdel/Fey6T/